For the partial fraction decomposition of any reell rational function complex conjugated poles imply complex conjugated coefficients
Every rational function $R(x)$ can be split up by Partial Fraction Decomposition:
\begin{equation}
R(x) = \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \frac{c_1}{x-\alpha_1} + \frac{c_2}{x-\alpha_2} + \cdots + \frac{c_n}{x-\alpha_n}
\end{equation}
Whereas $\alpha_i$ are the pols of $R(x)$ and the roots of $Q(x)$ and $c_i$ are the coefficients of the pols.
I want to show that for real $R(x)$: $\qquad\qquad \alpha_i = \overline{\alpha_j} \quad \implies \quad c_i = \overline{c_j}$
This would be usefull if you have conjugated pols (which you do have most of the time), then you'd only need to calculate one coefficient.
I found a proof but I don't know if it's currently rigorous.

It is given that every real polynomial can be expressed as a product of real polynomials of degree $\leq 2$.
Since R(x) is real, so is $Q(x)$. So we can decompose $Q(x)$ into a product of real polynomials of the form $x^2+px+q$ with $p,q \in \mathbb{R}$.
Using the quadratic formula we get:
\begin{equation}
x^2+px+q = \bigg(x-\bigg(\underbrace{\frac{-p}{2}}_{A}+\sqrt{\smash[b]{\underbrace{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}_{D}} }\bigg)\bigg)\bigg(x-\bigg(\frac{-p}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{p^2}{4}-q}\bigg)\bigg)=(x-A-\sqrt{D})(x-A+\sqrt{D})
\end{equation}
Since the roots of $Q(x)$ are the pols of $R(x)$ the terms in the PFD can be of the form
\begin{equation}
\frac{c}{x^2+px+q} = \frac{c}{(x-A-\sqrt{D})(x-A+\sqrt{D})}\, \qquad c\in\mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
Using PFD on this term we get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{cC}{(x-A-\sqrt{D})}+\frac{c(-C)}{(x-A+\sqrt{D})} \text{ with } C = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{D}}
\end{equation}
If $D<0$ then it is easy to see that $A-\sqrt{D} = \overline{A+\sqrt{D}}$ and $\overline{cC} = -cC$ hence the statement is proven.

I'm almost certain there are more straight forward ways to do this.
